# Scaling map for certain layers using CARTO?

Tags: carto, scale, zoom

I would like layer setup in CARTO - scaling map for certain layers.

How do I change the zoom, for example, on map markers, so that they are not displayed at all scales?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to use [Conditional CartoCSS](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/basic-cartocss-for-map-styling#cartocss-conditional-styling) to style your markers or other features on your map.

To do so inside CARTO Builder:

1. Click on the layer you want to style and switch to the **STYLE** tab.
2. On the bottom, click on the slider to switch to the CartoCSS console.
3. Apply a condition on the **zoom** value.

For example,

```
#layer {
  [zoom > 5] {
    marker-width: 20;
    marker-fill: #FF0000
  }
  [zoom > 10] {
    marker-width: 40;
    marker-fill: #00FF00
  }
}
```

would style points in red and with size 20 for zoom levels higher than 5, and in green and size 40 for zoom levels higher than 10. The points would be invisible for zoom levels equal to or smaller than 5.